# Pop up message in dynamically generated HTML table

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a web page in asp.net c# .In this I am creating a dynamic HTML table from code behind. Now I want a pop up message block when I move mouse over the last column of that dynamic generated HTML table. And this pop up block should show the test of cell on which mouse is moved.

Comment: to display tooltip you should start using javascript/jquery. here is a very good tooltip/popup plugins..

http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the mouse over event for the last td and then show a dialog using [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/). Please use the following code update its selector as per your page dom and also elaborate what do you mean by Test of cell?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#tableid td:last-child).mouseover(function (event) {
    var cellDialog = $('<div id="cellDialog">Display text will come here, you can grab the value of an cell in that particular row by navigating using the parent method or what ever your requirement is.</div>');
    cellDialog.css('display', 'none');
    $('body').append(cellDialog);
    $(cellDialog).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      draggable: false,
      resizable: false,
      modal: true,
      stack: true,
      position: 'center',
      closeOnEscape: true
    });
   });
});
```